# Getting setuptools version conflict when downloading tabula

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, tabula

I am trying to move my project onto another machine, but am having some difficulties setting up. The issue here is this:

When I run the `python setup.py install` command for the package `tabula`, I get an error saying this:

```
C:\Users\CeonzoJ\Desktop\tabula-py-master>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a prob
lem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
 verify failed (_ssl.c:748) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\ceonzoj\appdata\local\pro
grams\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\CeonzoJ\Desktop\tabula-py-master>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    'requests',
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils
\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1115, in best_match
    dist = working_set.find(req)
  File "C:\Users\CeonzoJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 719, in find
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 28.8.0 (c:\users\ceonzoj\appdata\loca
l\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>
=30'))
```

This is on my work computer, so I can't really just do this super simply through pip or anything like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to run `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org setuptools --upgrade` and then build your package.

Comment: How can I do this without calling the pip command? I am on my work computer so I can't call a pip install from an outside website such as pypi.

Comment: I typically install all of my modules through downloading the tar.gz and then running python setup.py install

Comment: You can use `pip install` for local files as well: `pip install ./downloads/SomePackage-1.0.4.tar.gz`

Comment: Hi - I am still getting issues with this. Does it mean that I need to update my `setuptools`?

Comment: Looks like it. Can you install latest `setuptools` by either using `pip` to download from `pypi` or have the `tar.gz` somewhere offline and run the above command?